# Como comparar 2 listas de una en python que se carga desde una fila de excel

Tags: python, excel

Hola espero que me puedan ayudar.

Tengo 2 archivos de excel

Archivo A
[image: Archivo A]

y
Archivo B
[image: archivo B]

Lo que intento hacer es meter esos datos a un arreglo por cada archivo y despues en caso de que la columna zona tenga celdas vacias las reemplace con un " - "

Despues de eso debo quitar de ambos arreglos las filas que en la columna Zona no tengan un guion, osea si tienen nombre que se quiten y se queden las que tienen guion

Despues de eso comparar si los  id del archivo B estan en A, si no estan se borran los que esten y se dejan los que no estan

Hasta ahora llevo esto

```
archivoA = pd.read_csv('a.csv', header=0,encoding='latin1',delimiter=',')
archivoB = pd.read_csv('v.csv',delimiter=',', header=0,encoding='latin1')

cpA = archivoA .loc[:,"Zona"]
cpB = archivoB.loc[:,"Zona"]

#Con este le reemplazo las celdas vacias de Zona por guiones " - "
cpA = cpCep.fillna("-")
cpB = cpCep.fillna("-")



 #aquí estoy intentando comparar si no tienen el guion que se eliminen de la lista 
    for iterador in cpA:
         if iterador.loc[:,"Zona"] == "-":
            cpA.pop(iterador)
     
print(cpA)
```

Se que no es mucho, no conozco bien las librerias de python y en los foros solo me he enredado

me podrían ayudar al menos en que se puedan eliminar las filas que no tengan guion en la columna de zona porfa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar siplemente [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) con un filtro.

Ejemplo completo utilizando el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
      Nombre     Zona
0   Portugal  Primera
1     México      NaN
2     España      NaN
3  Guatemala   Novena
```

Código:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Nombre': ['Portugal', 'México', 'España', 'Guatemala'],
                   'Zona': ['Primera', np.nan, np.nan, 'Novena']})

# Reemplazamos Nan por '-'
df['Zona'].fillna('-', inplace = True)

# Filtramos las filas que tengan '-' en la columna "Zona"
print(df.loc[df['Zona'] == '-'])
```

Esto devuelve el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
   Nombre Zona
1  México    -
2  España    -
```

**Nota adicional:** Al utilizar `pandas` es recomendable no utilizar ciclos (Por ejemplo `for`) para iterar en los elementos, hay métodos optimizados que trabajan con el `dataset` rápida y eficientemente. En la mayoría de los casos, si lo que quieres hacer crees que se puede hacer con un `for` entonces es el camino incorrecto (O el que va a tardar más y tener mayor impacto al procesador). En esos casos, si no hay un método directo que realice la tarea entonces apply podría ser una buena opción, como último recurso sería utilizar ciclos.